# Swagger response type getting defaulted to void unless ApiOperation.response() explicitly provided

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, swagger

I have an application for my REST APIs using jersey (version 1.17).
I am trying to set up swagger to document the same using swagger-maven-plugin (version 2.2)

Swagger documentation suggests:

> In JAX-RS applications, the return type of the method would automatically be used, 
>     unless it is   {@code javax.ws.rs.core.Response}.In that case, the operation return type would default to `void` as the actual response type cannot be known.

I am using a custom object (not javax.ws.rs.core.Response) as my method return type.
But the response type remains void unless I specify it as part of the ApiOperation annotation.

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@ApiOperation(
    value = "Description",
    response = MyCustomResponse.class
)
public MyCustomResponse myApiMethod() {
    return apiResponse;
}
```

I want to remove the response value from the annotation.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably a bit too late, but...
Can you share what MyCustomResponse is? Specifically, does it inherit from `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`? Or is it just a regular DTO?